# How do I incorporate a custom Power BI page into my custom component (simple HTML element) using TypeScript?

Tags: powerbi

I have a simple custom component using TypeScript for Power BI. I want to add a Power BI tooltip page to my custom component. I have already added tooltip settings in the capabilities.json file and enabled the tooltip option in the Power BI report menu. However, I am looking to integrate the tooltip page into the component.

expectin to have a tooltip page on my simple custom component.